# proper implementation of copy constructor for a linked list

Tags: c++, pointers, constructor, linked-list, copy-constructor

I am attempting to implement linked list, with certain methods made to supplement the linked list. 
However once I copy the linked list, and delete the head of the first linked list, and implement my overloaded operator "<<" to output the linked list, I get an error

```
Unhandled exception at 0x0128506C in program.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFEEEFEF2.
```

How do you copy the linked list without depending on the first linked list.

```
NodeSLList list2 (list1); //copy constructor 
temp = list1.DeleteFromHead();
cout << "node retrieved " << temp.data << endl;
cout << "cout << list1 " << endl;
cout << list1 << endl;
cout << list2 << endl; //error occurs
```

copy constructor

```
NodeSLList::NodeSLList(NodeSLList & list)
{
    head = list.head;
    tail = list.tail; 
    cout << "copy constructor called" << endl;

}
```

Comment: A linked list copy constructor is supposed to create a copy of the linked list.  Just making copies of the pointer values does not do this.  You need to recreate the entire linked list from scratch in the copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your copy constructor doesn't do copy. It only make new list to point onto first and last nodes oof your original list.

Basicly you need loop traversing every node of your original list and invoke copy constructor for each of them linking neighbouring copies together.

```
Node* n=list.head;
Node* prv=0;
while (n)
{
    Node* cpy = new Node(*n);
    if (prv)
        prv->next=cpy;
    else
        head=cpy;

    n=n->next;
    prv=cpy;
}
tail=prv;
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing with this code is just creating a list pointing to the same elements.
You'll need to traverse through the entire list and call copy constructors for all members. You need to recreate the list.

If you have some 'push', 'add' or 'insert' function you use for pushing elements to the list, use that function to recreate the list.